# Sql Server Analysis Server Filter Connection Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am using Sql Server Analysis Web-part and when I try to give connection to excel web access web-part from SSAS  I am not getting any options to give connection as below though it has OD connection in SSAS,But SSAS web-part is holding the values of the connection.Can any one help me how can I solve this asap
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changed the Master page to v4.master and it worked